# enter a formula that shows on clicking in a cell using vba then use it in solver

Tags: vba, excel, solver

Usually when i enter a formula on  excel it shows when i click on the cell, but when i use vba it only shows the value even when i click. I need to show the formula so i can use it as a target cell for a solver. The solver won't work if it's just a value.

Like for example i use

```
 Set srange1 = Range("B2:B" & n + 1)
 Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(2, 3 + n).Value = Application.Sum(srange1)
```

The cell contains only a value so i can't use a solver on it since it requires a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this

```
Set srange1 = Range("B2:B" & n + 1)
Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(2, 3 + n).Formula = "=SUM(" & srange1 .Address & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i needed